# I want to do -Back to the future- like flame stripes

Tags: fire

Im currently trying to recreate the flame stripes from Back to the future.

I only need a still frame.

This is what i want:

[image: This is what i want:]

And i only get this working with a basic fire sim:

[image]

Is there a good way to recreate these specific flames ?
Maybe even without a fire-sim ?

Comment: I think you're on the right track with a fire sim, but you might want to bump up the resolution. Also a wind force field might not be a bad idea. See the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/types/domain.html?#note-on-divisions-and-high-resolution) for some examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Final:

[image: final]

### Emitter:

For **Emitter/Flow** I've used two **Planes** with some **Loop Cuts** sized differently to have random fire width. Important thing is here real world scale. Both of them are 10m long and ~15cm width. Scale applied (!).

I've assigned **Transparent** material to them so they are not visible in render.

[image: flow]

### Domain:

Domain has pretty high **Resolution** along with **Smoke High Resolution**. Settings like below.

Material is simple, without smoke.

[image: domain]

### Wind:

Last part is **Force Field > Wind** with some **Noise**.

[image: wind]

> If you need any specific explanation, please ask in comments.

Comment: this already looks really great. Thanks you. Is there to seperate the flames even down to the emitter ? In the BTTF-Photo the flames are clearly seperated. And in the fire sim they always fuse to one glowing blob near at the emitter. Also they emit from everywhere. Is there a way to add maybe a noise texture to control the emission  ? Or will i need to do multiple separated emitters for that ?

Comment: @JensClar sadly this blob is a "feature" and only way to reduce it is to set Flow source > Surface to minimum (0.5). You can also change width of the emitter to something really low, like 1cm or even less to have it smaller. Another method would be to just lower emitter below ground plane. Sadly again you can't use textures with smoke/fire sim to have some noise. I've showed you the way to vary thickness of it, but you can make more emitters if you want. Mantaflow simulations are pretty close to be in Blender 2.8, this should help with those issues. For now we have what we have...

Comment: ok i have not worked on this since you posted your answer. But how do you get the transparent input in the color ramp ?

Comment: @JensClar when selecting color in Color Picker, use A value to change alpha (transparency). https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/controls/templates/color_picker.html