# Electric fireplace

Tags: fire

What's the best way to create fire in electric fireplace like this?

[image]

I'm creating interior and I want to achieve most realistic effect I can.
I appreciate all the tips. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?ei=L-WWWvm4HZK2sAWTiICoDg&q=blender+3d+fire&oq=blender+3d+fire&gs_l=psy-ab.12..0j0i22i30k1l7j0i22i10i30k1.26581.34835.0.37843.7.7.0.0.0.0.106.675.6j1.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.7.670...0i131i67k1j0i7i30k1.0.UdTyjOVyOi4

Comment: Related or even duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99732/i-want-to-do-back-to-the-future-like-flame-stripes/99739#99739 Just don't add Force Field to this answer.